# Generating MD5 hashes for all files in the current folder including all files in subfolders

Tags: python, directory, md5, subdirectory

with the help of this thread

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147056/short-script-to-hash-files-in-a-directory

I managed to get almost exactly what i needed. The given code is

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join, normpath, basename
import hashlib


def get_files():
    current_path = normpath(getcwd())
    return [join(current_path, f) for f in listdir(current_path) if isfile(join(current_path, f))]


def get_hashes():
    files = get_files()
    list_of_hashes = []
    for each_file in files:
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(each_file, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
        list_of_hashes.append('Filename: {}\tHash: {}\n'.format(basename(each_file), hash_md5.hexdigest()))
    return list_of_hashes


def write_hashes():
    hashes = get_hashes()
    with open('list_of_hashes.txt', 'w') as f:
        for md5_hash in hashes:
            f.write(md5_hash)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_hashes()
```

However, additionally i'd  like to consider all the files that are in subfolders of my given path and include them into the output. I tried using os.walk() but i didn't manage to succeed.

Can you help me adjusting the function get_files() such that it generates the MD5 hashes for all files in subfolders (i.e. considers the entire folder structure?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
current_path = normpath(getcwd())
listOfFiles = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(current_path):
    listOfFiles += [join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]
```

(based on [this source](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-get-list-of-files-in-directory-and-sub-directories/))